# mysql joining 3 tables together is performing slow -- how to properly index?

Tags: mysql

I have 3 mysql tables that I am trying to join together.

1. snapshots
2. snapshots_source
3. snapshots_image

snapshots containers the core description.

snapshots_source is 1:1 relationship with snapshots using snapshot_id as the xref

snapshots_image is a 1:Many, relationship with snapshots, where there can be many images referring back to the same snapshot_id.
an snapshot_id record may not exist but I still want it to be returned as long snapshot and source finds a matching record.

```
CREATE TABLE `snapshots` (
  `snapshot_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `email` varchar(256) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `seed` varchar(256) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `date_sent` datetime NOT NULL,
  `date_created` datetime NOT NULL,
  `date_modified` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `subject` varchar(1024) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `html` longtext COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `size` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `status` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT '-1= error, 0 = new, 1 = approved, 2 = review ',
  `archive` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`snapshot_id`),
  KEY `snapshot_id` (`snapshot_id`),
  KEY `date_sent` (`date_sent`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=251398 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci ROW_FORMAT=COMPACT


CREATE TABLE `snapshots_source` (
  `ss_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `snapshot_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `html` longtext COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ss_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `snapshot_id_UNIQUE` (`snapshot_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=176129 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci ROW_FORMAT=COMPACT


CREATE TABLE `snapshots_images` (
  `si_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `snapshot_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `image` text COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `dimensions` varchar(16) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`si_id`),
  KEY `snapshot_id` (`snapshot_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=287890 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci ROW_FORMAT=COMPACT
```

Here is my query:

```
SELECT sn.email, sn.date_sent, sn.subject, sh.html, sn.size, si.image, si.dimensions
FROM snapshots sn
INNER JOIN snapshots_source sh ON sh.snapshot_id = sn.snapshot_id
LEFT JOIN snapshots_images si ON sn.snapshot_id = si.snapshot_id
ORDER BY sn.date_sent DESC
LIMIT 10;
```

I am getting the following:

```
id,select_type,table,type,possible_keys,key,key_len,ref,rows,Extra
1,SIMPLE,sn,index,"PRIMARY,snapshot_id",date_sent,5,,1000,
1,SIMPLE,sh,ref,snapshot_id,snapshot_id,5,mockd.sn.snapshot_id,1,
1,SIMPLE,si,ref,snapshot_id,snapshot_id,4,mockd.sn.snapshot_id,1,
```

Seems like its indexing but still slow for 1000 results. This took 4.43 seconds.

My expected results.
Lets start with snapshots_images.
This contains any images can be associated to snapshots via the snapshot_id index.

ex:

```
snapshots_images
================
si_id snapshot_id image dimension
1 1 some_url 100x100
2 1 some_url 100x100
3 2 some_url 100x100
4 4 some_url 100x100
```

As you can see here, snapshot_id 3 is missing because a snapshot does not always have an image associated, but it can support multiple if needed like snapshot 1.

```
snapshots_source
================
ss_id snapshot_id html
1 1 'some html'
2 2 'some html'
3 3 'some html'
4 4 'some html'
5 6 'some html'
```

as you can see here, there can only be one snapshot_id here that can associate back to snapshots.snapshot_id. the snapshot_id in this case is unique for this table.

```
snapshots
=========
snapshot_id email
1 'some email'
2 'some email'
3 'some email'
4 'some email'
5 'some email'
6 'some email'
```

I am over simplifying here, so some fields are not displayed in the example.
In this case since snapshot_id 5 has no record within snapshots_source, the results should not display any with snapshot_id 5

My expected results would look like:

```
snapshot_id email html image dimensions
1 'some email' 'some html' 'some url' 100x100
2 'some email' 'some html' 'some url' 100x100
3 'some email' 'some html' null null
4 'some email' 'some html' 'some url' 100x100
6 'some email' 'some html' null null
```

Question: Is there anyway to further optimize this?
The expected query may be around 10,000 results.
Any help would be appreciated

Comment: `snapshots_source` or `snapshots_html`?

Comment: Snapshots_html was renamed to snapshots_source. They are one in the same

Comment: This sort of question cannot be answered without looking at explain output

Comment: Also show a sample of what your expected output is, there maybe a different query that gets the same result more quickly

Comment: _"an snapshot_id record may not exist but I still want it to be returned as long snapshot and source finds a matching record."_ this statement is confusing me a little. You want an `snapshot_image` record if it has no corresponding `snapshots` record? Despite ordering by that table's `date_sent`?

Comment: I will add some examples as soon as I get back to my desk

Comment: revised question and simplified things abit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your indexes look fine, if a bit redundant in places, my guess at the source of the slowness would be the presence of large `TEXT` fields combined with the `ORDER BY` and `LIMIT` (it can't reduce the result set until after ordering the entire result set; I would hope internally it would defer loading the larger fields uninvolved with the ordering, but it might not).

You might have some success with:

```
SELECT sn.email, sn.date_sent, sn.subject, sh.html, sn.size, si.image, si.dimensions
FROM (
   SELECT snapshot_id, email, date_sent, subject, size
   FROM snapshots
   ORDER BY date_sent DESC
   LIMIT 10
) AS sn
LEFT JOIN snapshots_html sh ON sh.snapshot_id = sn.snapshot_id
INNER JOIN snapshots_images si ON sn.snapshot_id = si.snapshot_id
LIMIT 10;
```

Note that I `LIMIT`ed twice because the later join may multiply the results. However, I note that the last join is an inner, so it may actually reduce the results as well.

Comment: Thank you for this as this helped me realize i should be using the INNER JOIN first. I updated my question, made some changes and used the INNER JOIN first since HTML must be a match before even considering the images. But still quite slow for 1000 records. Please advise any other suggestion.

Comment: For testing purposes, try `SELECT 1 ` to simplify things, and removing different join "lines" to determine which join is costing you the most. Did you try performing the initial ordering and limiting in a subquery as my answer suggested?